# How to pass a variable to a helper and display its in the template?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, meteor

I'd like to collect a variable(user _id)collected from a template, and pass it to another template using session. Then I want to display this variable.
Actually it seems to work in the collection of the variable and the pass to the other template, but I'm not able to display the user's info in the second template...

This is my code:

HTML

```
<template name="main"><!--Template 1-->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Patient</th>
        </tr>
        {{#each allUsers}}
        <tr>
            <th><label><input type="radio" class="selected" name="patient" value="{{this._id}}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{this.profile.lastName}} {{this.profile.firstName}}</label></th>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>

   {{>test}}
</template>

<template name="test"> <!--Template 2-->
   <p>Name is <button class="test" name="patient" value="{{this._id}}">Test</button></p>
   <div name="show">Name: {{this.profile.firstName}}</div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.main.events({
'click .selected': function (){
var selPat = $('input[name="patient"]:checked').val();
Session.set("selPat",selPat);
console.log("collect", selPat);
}
});

Template.test.events({
    'click .test': function(){
        var PAT= Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: Session.get("selPat")});
        console.log("pass", PAT);
        return PAT;
    }

});
Template.patients.helpers({
   allUsers: function() {
       return Meteor.users.find({});
   }
});
```

I want to display in the template 2 the first name of the user selected in the template 1 with {{this.profile.firstName}}

Comment: ```Template.test.events```  You are mixing both event and helper functionality here. The ```return PAT``` should be in a helper and not the event itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are doing:

1. You are choosing patient's id from a list of patients via the radio buttons in the main template. [this implementation is correct]
2. You are setting the patient id in a session in the main template's events. [this implementation is correct]
3. When you click the "test" button in the test template, it should reveal the user's first name in the div below the button. [...not quite]

You are unable to display anything in `<div name="show">Name: {{this.profile.firstName}}</div>` because you don't have a relevant helper supplying the template with that information.

---

Although clicking a button to reveal the patient's firstName in the test template sounds a bit redundant, I'm sure you have some reason to do it in that manner.

I propose that you wrap the div inside an [`if block`](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#if-else). The if condition renders true, when the button is clicked, and hence the div element is shown.

```
<template name="test"> <!--Template 2-->
   <p>Name is <button class="test" name="patient" value="{{this._id}}">Test</button></p>

{{#if isButtonClicked}}
   <div name="show">Name: {{data.profile.firstName}}</div>
{{/if}}

</template>
```

Your helpers and events will be like so:

```
Template.test.events({
    'click .test': function(){
      // set this session to true when the button has been clicked.
      Session.set("testClicked", true);

     }
});

Template.test.helpers({
     isButtonClicked: function(){
      // return the if block's validation.
      return Session.get("testClicked");
     },

     data: function(){
        // return the actual user data retrieved from the collection.
        var PAT= Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: Session.get("selPat")});
        console.log("pass", PAT);
        return PAT;
});
```

---

**Note:**
You might want to make sure that the div does not stay open when you select a different patient from the list of radio buttons. Not doing so will make the div be visible when you first click the button, and remain open until you refresh the page, even when you select a different patient. 
You could set `testClicked` to `false` or `undefined` in `Template.main.events` --> `'click .selected'`

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need!

Comment: Now let say that I have multiple template to display in this way and if I change the selected radio button the previous will dissapear and the new will display the relative template.... How can I do this?